# PHP Parse Number From Complicated String

Tags: php, regex

I am looping through an array, and have multiple entries that would be returned  like this.

```
llll-aaaa-dddd.zzzz-124
xxd98sss-61
fff.sss-ddx-74
```

I need a way in PHP to parse out the last number after the last dash on every iteration, so that I can use it on another function call.

These entries can possibly have other dashes, other numbers, etc... But the last number will always have a hyphen and then the number. I need only that complete last number after the hyphen.

Any regex gurus out there able to lend a hand?

Comment: explode on dash, get last element of array

Comment: I think `.*-(\d+)` would do it. Negative numbers and decimaled numbers would have issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a simple regular expression, hardly requiring a guru.

```
preg_match('/-(\d+)$/', $line, $match);
$num = $match[1];
```

`\d+` matches a sequence of digits, and `$` matches the end of the string. The parentheses define a capture group, and `$match[1]` contains the contents of the group.

Answer (score 0):

Have tried this `preg_match("/(\d*)$/", $input_line, $output_array)`. it returns digits at the end of the string

`preg_match("/(-\d*)$/", $input_line, $output_array);` . this returns the last digits along with the hype "-".